# Почему каждый 2 ряд пикселей в bitmap белого цвета при конвертировании BGR -> RGBA?

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, jni

UPD. Решение все ещё не найдено, а в комментариях, можно сказать, одна вода, которая не даёт чёткого исправления проблемы. В комментах пишут, мол из-за целочисленного деления я получаю такой результат. Если я уберу деление на 4, то почему тогда я получаю аналогичное изображение с перезаписанными пикселями? Что интересно, в реализации `java` по ссылке, которой я прикрепил - там нет деления на 4 и результат отображается корректный. Я пока не понял, почему деление на 4 в `c++` дало мне масштаб картинки 1 к 1, а в `java` без него тот же масштаб. Если в плюсах не писать деление на 4 - тогда я получаю только четверть картинки, и тоже с белыми линиями.

**UPD2.** Решение найдено. Но я просто хочу понять - почему в плюсах мы делим `rowBytes` на 4, а в java в том примере по ссылке, которой я прикрепил - там нет деления, там только +4. При этом результаты одинаковы. В чем подвох, или где я что упустил?

Мне нужно преобразовать `bgr`-массив в `rgb`-массив. Я бы рад воспользоваться реализацией из существующих библиотек, но они слишком медленные для моего проекта.

У меня есть собственная `jni`-функция, написанная на `c++`, которая конвертирует массив, а быть точнее `Frame` из `FFmpegFrameGrabber`, который будет записан после конвертации в `Bitmap`. Я из этого пакета только забираю оттуда:

`(ByteBuffer) frame.image[0]; // здесь кадр в bgr-формате`

Я знаю, что в `opencv` и `javacv` существуют разные конвертеры, но для моего проекта очень важна производительность, так как кадр должен будет попасть на мою нейронку. Поэтому конвертирование в матрицу, а потом конвертирование через `Utils.matToBitmap` или `AndroidFrameConverter`, у которого задержка составялет ~ 50 ms меня не устраивает. Хотя нативный метод `matToBitmap` очень быстрый, но он не подходит, потому что конвертирование `javacv Mat` в `opencvMat` занимает ~ 100 ms, что очень много. `cvtColor` не подходит по аналогичной проблеме, потому что принимает на вход матрицу.

Собственный конвертер на `c++` я писал исходя [AndroidFrameConverter](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacv/AndroidFrameConverter.java) из метода:

`ByteBuffer bgr2rgba(ByteBuffer in, int width, int height, int stride, int rowBytes{...}`

Писал конвертер только для `ARGB_8888`, то есть 4 байта на пиксель. Сейчас мой код затрачивает на конвертацию ~8-15 ms. Но я не понимаю, где я упустил часть кода, что каждый 2 ряд пикселей у `Bitmap` не отображаются.  Так как я не силен в плюсах, поэтому собрал вот такой код:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <endian.h>

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_example_testcpp_MainActivity_frameToBitmap(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject in,
                                                    jint width, jint height, jint imageStride,
                                                    jint rowBytes) {

 auto* buf = (uint8_t*)  env->GetDirectBufferAddress(in);

    int* new_buff = new int [4*width*height];

    int _width = width - 1;
    int _height = height - 1;

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        int ro = y * imageStride;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            int rgb;
            if (x < _width || y < _height) {
                rgb = *(int*)(buf + y * imageStride + 3 * x);
            } else {
                int b = buf[ro + 3 * x    ] & 0xff;
                int g = buf[ro + 3 * x + 1] & 0xff;
                int r = buf[ro + 3 * x + 2] & 0xff;
                rgb = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
            }
            new_buff[y / 4 * rowBytes + x] = htobe32((rgb << 8) | 0xff);
        }
    }
    jbyteArray jByteArray = env->NewByteArray((jsize)4*width*height);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(jByteArray, 0, 4*width*height, reinterpret_cast<const jbyte*>(new_buff));
    delete[] new_buff;
    return jByteArray;
}
```

Вот какое изображение на выходе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где я допустил ошибку в `c++` коде??

`java` вызов функции:

```
Frame frame = grabber.grabImage();
ByteBuffer in = (ByteBuffer)frame.image[0];
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(frame.imageWidth, frame.imageHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
byte [] data = frameToBitmap(in, frame.imageWidth, frame.imageHeight, frame.imageStride, bmp.getRowBytes());
bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(data).position(0));
```

Может кто-то знает быстрое преобразование `javacv Mat` в `opencv Mat` и затем конвертирование через быстрый нативный метод `Utils.matToBitmap`, чтобы не создавать свою `jni`-функцию? Было бы неплохо услышать еще, как можно оптимизировать и ускорить данный код.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138304/discussion-on-question-by-denrudi---2----bitmap--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде по ссылке вычисляется адрес в буфере (в байтах), по которому записывается int, здесь у вас интовый массив, индекс в котором в 4 раза меньше.

При использовании целочисленного деления, как написали в комментариях, результат получается не тот, что вы ожидали, т.к. `0/4 = 1/4 = 2/4 = 3/4 = 0`. Так работает целочисленное деление и в С, и в Java.

Для получения правильного результата в данном случае достаточно сначала выполнить умножение, потом уже делить:

```
new_buff[y * rowBytes / 4 + x] =
```

Comment: Теперь все стало на свои места с делением на 4, спасибо! С целоцисленным делением  (хотя знал об этом и раньше) я запутался только из-за того, потому что индекс массива всегда же должен быть целочисленным - это сбило меня с толку

Comment: не могли бы Вы взглянуть, пожалуйста, на мой еще один вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1446318/Почему-cmath-не-вычисляет-корректно-синус-и-выдает-ошибку-без-stacktrace, там похожая проблема с делением массива на 4, но пока неизвестно, где еще нужно делить, и там картинка становится еще желтоватого оттенка