# Почему cmath не вычисляет корректно синус и выдает ошибку (без stacktrace)?

Tags: java, android, c++, алгоритм, jni

Стоит задача переписать код из этого [сайта](https://www.helviojunior.com.br/fotografia/barrel-and-pincushion-distortion/) для фильтра бочкообразной/подушкообразной дисторсии с `C#` на `Java`, а затем на `JNI C++` для `Android`. Переписать на `Java` не составило труда, код работает идеально, а вот с `C++` возникли проблемы (знаком с ним ~ 2 дня). `OpenCV` в качестве решения не рассматриваю, потому что мое приложение и так уже много весит.

Так вот, когда происходит ошибка, `Android Studio` не выдает нормальный `stacktrace` для нативного кода, поэтому я юзал для этих целей дебаггер. Все что он выдает, так это только номер строки, где происходит ошибка и больше ничего, поэтому код пишется, можно сказать, только с одним открытым глазом.

Что интересно, ошибка происходит только тогда, когда разрешение изображения слишком большое - например 1270x720 не работает, но если я передам в свой `JNI C++` код изображение с разрешением, например, 150x50, тогда иногда даже выводится какой-то `Bitmap`, но это происходит не всегда - **это поведение очень странное для меня.** Так как неизвестно, что это за ошибка, отладчик ничего не выдает, поэтому я даже разбил код на части, и ошибка происходит тогда, когда вычисляется синус в функции `newPoint`. Почему происходит ошибка, пока что остается для меня загадкой.

На вход всегда 1 и 2 параметром подается `Bitmap ARGB8888`. 3 параметр - коэффициент искажения от -1 до 1. Первый битмап - это исходное изображение, а во второй битмап записывается результат искажений.

Вот сам код:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/bitmap.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <android/log.h>

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

Point newPoint(int x, int y, int width,  int height, double amplitude, bool inverse) {
    int pY;
    int pX;
    double aY = 0;
    double aX = 0;

    double angX = M_PI * 1 * (double) x / (double) width;
    double caX = amplitude * ((((double) height / 2) - (double) y) / ((double) height / 2));

    double angY = M_PI * 1 * (double) y / (double) height;
    double caY = amplitude * ((((double) width / 2) - (double) x) / ((double )width / 2));

    if (inverse) {
        double iAng = M_PI * -1 * 0.5;
        aX = (caX * sin(iAng));
        aY = (caY * sin(iAng));
    }

    pX = (int)(x + aY + caY * sin(angY));
    pY = (int)(y + aX + caX * sin(angX)); // <- ошибка происходит вот здесь через несколько итераций в цикле, а именно при вычислении синуса.
    // Интересно, что ошибка может возникнуть и в другом месте, где вычисляется синус
    return Point{pX, pY};
}

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL
Java_rta_denrudi_newtestdist_ImageFilter_distortion(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,
                                                      jobject startImage, jobject finalImage, jdouble factor) {

    AndroidBitmapInfo startInfo;
    void *startPixels;
    void *finalPixels;

    AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, startImage, &startInfo);
    AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, startImage, &startPixels);
    AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, finalImage, &finalPixels);

    auto *srcPixels = (int32_t *) startPixels;
    auto *dstPixels = (int32_t *) finalPixels;


    int depth = 32;
    int cCount = depth / 8;
    int sWidth = startInfo.width;
    int sHeight = startInfo.height;

    double amp = 0;
    double ang = M_PI * 0.5;

    for (int a = 0; a < sHeight; a++) {
        int y = (int) (((float)sHeight / 2) - amp * sin(ang));
        if ((y < 0) || (y > sHeight))
            break;
        amp = a;
    }
    amp = (amp - 2) * (factor < -1 ? -1 : (factor > 1 ? 1 : factor));

    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
    x1 = sWidth;
    y1 = sHeight;
    x2 = 0;
    y2 = 0;

    int index = (sWidth + 1) * cCount;
    while (index < startInfo.stride * startInfo.height / 4) {
        int y = (int) ((index / cCount) / sWidth);
        int x = (index / cCount) - (y * sWidth);
        Point pt = newPoint(x, y, sWidth, sHeight, amp, factor < 0);

        if (factor >= 0) {
            if (x == sWidth / 2) {
                if (pt.y < y1)
                    y1 = pt.y;
                if (pt.y > y2)
                    y2 = pt.y;
            }

            if (y == sHeight / 2) {
                if (pt.x < x1)
                    x1 = pt.x;
                if (pt.x > x2)
                    x2 = pt.x;
            }
        } else {
            if ((x == 1) && (y == 1)) {
                y1 = pt.y;
                x1 = pt.x;
            }
            if ((x == sWidth - 1) && (y == sHeight - 1)) {
                y2 = pt.y;
                x2 = pt.x;
            }
        }

        int dstIndex = ((pt.y * sWidth) + pt.x) * cCount;
        dstPixels[dstIndex] = srcPixels[index++];
        dstPixels[dstIndex + 1] = srcPixels[index++];
        dstPixels[dstIndex + 2] = srcPixels[index++];
        dstPixels[dstIndex + 3] = srcPixels[index++];

    }
    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, startImage);
    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, finalImage);

    jintArray array = env->NewIntArray(4);
    jint values[4] = {x1, x2, y1, y2};
    env->SetIntArrayRegion(array, 0, 4, values);
    return array;
}
```

Почему происходит такая ошибка? И второстепенный вопрос, может кто подскажет, как настроить реальный вывод `stacktrace` в `Android Studio`? Ничего толкового не нашел на эту тему.

**UPD.** Есть некоторые изменения. Я попробовал убрать для теста вычисление синуса и дебаггер указал на `AndroidBitmap_lock...`. Непонятно, почему дебаггер указывал именно на синус. Вернул уже обратно вычисления синуса. Так вот, ошибка была вот здесь `while (index < startInfo.stride * startInfo.height) {` - нужно было поделить еще на 4, так как int массив в 4 раза меньше. Но на выходе все равно не то, что мне нужно. По идее нужно поделить и:

`int dstIndex = (((pt.y * sWidth) + pt.x) * cCount) / 4;`

Картинка как бы уже с корректными искажениями дисторсии, но вместо одной картинки - на выходе четыре, а еще она потеряла часть цвета, и стала желтоватого оттенка. Что я упустил? А еще почему-то не получается для 2 картинок сделать `lock` пикселей одновременно в функции - может что не так сделал, надо будет еще протестировать.

Насчет `stacktrace` - нашел в логкате `backtrace` нативного кода, но там все равно не очень понятно, какая допущена ошибка.

**UPD2.**
Насколько я правильно понял, изображение на `C++` было получено с тем инвертированным оттенком из-за формата `BGRA`, а мне нужно получить `RGBA`. Почему в `Java` и `C#` все нормально работает с каналами, а на `C++` надо менять? (Ниже привел свою реализацию на `java`). Банальное перемещение индекса не решает эту проблему. Например,

```
dstPixels[dstIndex + 2] = srcPixels[index++]; // b (0) -> r (2)
dstPixels[dstIndex + 1] = srcPixels[index++]; // g (1) -> g (1)
dstPixels[dstIndex + 0] = srcPixels[index++]; // r (2) -> b (0)
dstPixels[dstIndex + 3] = srcPixels[index++]; // a (3) -> a (3)
```

Почему именно в такой последовательности, потому что я думал что в массиве числа расположены  как `b`, `g`, `r`, `a` и при перемещении индекса, должно было получится как `rgba` но на деле это не так - картинка все равно инвертированная. Может я неправильно что-то указал? Нужно ли применять здесь битовые манипуляции, как я делал, например вот в этом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1435933/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B9-2-%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-bitmap-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-bgr-rg)? А с выводом картинки все такая же беда.

Ожидаемое изображение (запускал код на `java`):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаемое изображение (запускал код на `c++`):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для наглядности приведу еще и код на `java` (написан неаккуратно и на скорую руку для теста, но сути это не меняет, этот код рабочий)

```
    public static Bitmap distort(Bitmap startImage, double factor) {
        int depth = 32; // глубина изображения
        int cCount = depth / 8;

        int sWidth = startImage.getWidth();
        int sHeight = startImage.getHeight();
        byte[] srcPixels = new byte[sWidth * sHeight * 4];
        byte[] dstPixels = new byte[srcPixels.length];

        startImage.copyPixelsToBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(srcPixels));

 
        double amp = 0;
        double ang = Math.PI * 0.5;
        for (int a = 0; a < sHeight; a++) {
            int y = (int)((sHeight / 2) - amp * Math.sin(ang));
            if ((y < 0) || (y > sHeight))
                break;
            amp = a;
        }
        amp = (amp - 2) * (factor < -1 ? -1 : (factor > 1 ? 1 : factor));


        int x1, y1, x2, y2;
        x1 = sWidth;
        y1 = sHeight;
        x2 = 0;
        y2 = 0;
        int index = (sWidth + 1) * cCount;

        while (index < srcPixels.length) {
            int y = (int)((index / cCount) / sWidth);
            int x = (index / cCount) - (y * sWidth);
            Point pt = newPoint(new Point(x, y), sWidth, sHeight, amp, factor < 0);

            if (factor >= 0) {
                if (x == sWidth / 2) {
                    if (pt.y < y1)
                        y1 = pt.y;
                    if (pt.y > y2)
                        y2 = pt.y;
                }

                if (y == sHeight / 2) {
                    if (pt.x < x1)
                        x1 = pt.x;
                    if (pt.x > x2)
                        x2 = pt.x;
                }
            } else {
                if ((x == 1) && (y == 1)) {
                    y1 = pt.y;
                    x1 = pt.x;
                }
                if ((x == sWidth - 1) && (y == sHeight - 1)) {
                    y2 = pt.y;
                    x2 = pt.x;
                }
            }

            int dstIndex = ((pt.y * sWidth) + pt.x) * cCount;
            dstPixels[dstIndex] = srcPixels[index++];
            dstPixels[dstIndex + 1] = srcPixels[index++];
            dstPixels[dstIndex + 2] = srcPixels[index++];
            dstPixels[dstIndex + 3] = srcPixels[index++]; 
        }

        Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(sWidth, sHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        newImage.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(dstPixels));
        // imageView.setImageBitmap(newImage);
        return newImage;

    }

    private static Point newPoint(Point point, int width, int height, double amplitude, boolean inverse) {
        int pY, pX;
        double aY, aX;
        aY = aX = 0;

        double angX = Math.PI * 1 * (double) point.x / (double)width;
        double caX = amplitude * ((((double)height / 2) - (double) point.y) / ((double)height / 2));

        double angY = Math.PI * 1 * (double) point.y / (double)height;
        double caY = amplitude * ((((double)width / 2) - (double) point.x) / ((double)width / 2));

        if (inverse) {
            double iAng = Math.PI * -1 * 0.5;
            aX = (caX * Math.sin(iAng));
            aY = (caY * Math.sin(iAng));
        }

        pX = (int)(point.x + aY + caY * Math.sin(angY));
        pY = (int)(point.y + aX + caX * Math.sin(angX));

        return new Point(pX, pY);
    }
```

Comment: Android Studio из коробки должен позволять отлаживать нативный код. Результаты `AndroidBitmap_*` обязательно проверять. Ну и странно, что к `dstPixels` идет обращение, как будто это указатель на цветовой компонент.

Comment: У меня с коробки как на физическом устройстве так и на эмуляторе выдаёт только одну строку  типа `fatal exception, code 2...`, и на этом все. Ни трассировки, ни выводящих tombstones. `dstPixels` нужен только для 1 цели - записать новые искажнные пиксели первого изображения, по факту это просто выделенная память для второго битмапа

Comment: ¿Точка останова не ставится даже? А про `dstPixels` я писал в том ключе, что там неверное обращение по индексу

Comment: Точка останова как раз и ставится, это и есть дебаггер. Я с помощью него и определил, что на строке с вычислением синуса происходит ошибка, но какая - увы, пока не знаю, и студия не пишет

Comment: Ну так и stacktrace тот же дебаггер показывает и сообщение об ошибке он же пишет.

Comment: Скорее всего в логкате включен фильтр по процессу приложения, а креш дамп  улетает в общий лог (потому что процесс уже мёртв).

Comment: Процесс под дебагером не должен умирать и дампа не создается. В момент краша он должен сработать как точка останова в проблемном месте

Comment: Если вы неверно посчитали адрес памяти и записали что-то не туда, то вполне естественно что программа упадёт не при записи, а при обращении к тому участку памяти, который изменён. Я не особо понимаю что вы делаете, но вам нужно понять что `stride` - это оффсет от начала строки до начала следующей строки в **байтах**, а ширина и высота указаны в **пикселях**.

Comment: @woesss, спасибо, сейчас ещё раз пересмотрю логику с адресами памяти. Сам алгоритм на c# я взял отсюда: https://www.helviojunior.com.br/fotografia/barrel-and-pincushion-distortion/

Comment: У вас проблема та же, что и в том вопросе: вы в java работаете с байтовыми массивами, а в С++ с интовыми, но одинаковым кодом. *Банальное перемещение индекса* - вы меняете местами не каналы в пикселе, а целые пиксели местами, потому что интерпретировали указатель на память битмапа в `int32_t`, вместо `int8_t`

Comment: @woesss, тогда получается, что в функции newPoint в `C++` нужно при операциях с `x` и `y` и в самом цикле `while` при операции с каждым пикселем результат тоже делить на 4? И получается `dstIndex` тоже должен быть поделен на 4? Насчёт указателя - если интерпретировать в int8_t - тогда не нужно будет проводить манипуляции с битами?

Comment: Вы переносите код из java в плюсы, если входные данные будут одинакового типа, то и весь код будет максимально идентичным. Если что-то надо делить в java-коде, то и в плюсах будет также.

Comment: Зачем вы усложняете себе задачу интовыми массивами? Сделайте их байтовыми и никакой разницы в C++ у вас не будет - **просто перепишите код один-в-один** и всего делов. Никакие каналы там не разворачиваются - вы вместо канала берёте целый пиксель, от этого и цвета искажаются и пиксели уезжают не на место.

Comment: `Android Studio не выдает нормальный stacktrace для нативного кода` - Необязательно же отлаживать алгоритм именно на Android Studio. Возьмите любой другой компилятор и в нём проверьте проблемный код. А потом уже на Android Studio его можно будет перенести.

Comment: @woesss, спасибо за совет, уже нашел решение, и оно максимально простое). Я не знаю, почему я не доглядел это, может заработался, но вы были правы - нужно было привести указатели на пиксели двух изображений к `int_8t` и все. И цвета пикселей теперь корректные. Я думаю, что можете написать ответ.  По факту я ничего не выиграл - скорость работы на java была в пределах 20-30 ms, и такая же ситуация  и на плюсах (возможно это так на моем физическом устройстве).

Comment: ¿А скорость у релизного билда мерялась? Ну алгоритм стоило бы подработать, избавиться от всяких лишних `sin` `cos` на каждом шаге. А по-хорошему, это стоит на GPU переносить.